# Why I get error when I try to parse JSON in the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I pass JSON to the razor view page with help of ViewBag.

Here is the code in the action function:

```
    public ActionResult GmailOAuthCallback(string code)
    {
        object contacts = GmailServiceWorkflow.GetContacts(code);
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(contacts);
        ViewBag.name = json;
        return View("SomeWindow");
    }
```

At the razor view page I want to parse JSON to the object.

Here is the code in view razor page:

```
function myFunction() {
        var arrObject = JSON.parse("@ViewBag.name");
        alert(arrObject[0].firstName);
        }
```

But I get this error:

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data**

Any idea why I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: THe error states that the JSON-data is invalid. Your code has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `JavaScriptSerializer`, you ca acheive this by passing the collection to the view

```
public ActionResult GmailOAuthCallback(string code)
{
  object contacts = GmailServiceWorkflow.GetContacts(code);   
  ViewBag.name = contacts ;
  return View("SomeWindow");
}
```

then in the script

```
function myFunction() {
  var arrObject = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.name))');
  alert(arrObject[0].firstName);
}
```

Comment: Stephen thanks for the answer but I get red line(error) under Json.

Comment: What does the error indicate? You may be missing `<add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />` from your `web.config` file

Comment: @Michael That just means you need to include the relevant namespace, [System.Web.Helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), and either add a using statement and/or add the System.Web.Helpers to the web.config (as Stephen notes).

Comment: Yes,I know I already have @using System.Web.Helpers ,but steal I get  the error

Comment: Strange, works for me. The script is not in a external file is it?